# NAudio - How to change frequency at runtime (Doppler)

Tags: frequency, volume, naudio

I'd like to know if there is a way to change the frequency(pitch) and volume of the audio while playing in **NAudio**. I'd like to simulate the **Doppler** effect. The observer is in the middle and does not move. While the moving object is going to the observer its **"voice"** has one **frequency/pitch**, later on when as he goes past the observer it has another **frequency/pitch**.

[image]

The green circle is the observer and the smaller blue circle is the moving object. When the objects x coordinate is the same as the observers x coordinate an event happens which should change the pitch/frequency.

I want to play the **same sound**, just with 2 **different frequencies** while the sound keeps playing. Something like a **sudden pitch shift**. I've read that pitch shifting is not supported in NAudio though.

Comment: The volume part got solved and is available here https://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/590875

Comment: Take a look at this [Skype voice changer](https://skypefx.codeplex.com/), it uses NAudio and it has and _effect_ called SuperPitch, it could be a place to start.